# S30+ Game Development

Tags: windows, linux, development, game, windowsphone

How can I get started developing games for the S30+ operating system on Windows or Linux?

I have a new nokia 150, which seems to run the correct operating system, although I'm not sure if this phone is bricked or not.  However, there are other models out there such as the 6310.  I think with the 6310 it is indeed possible to run old .vxp files and play games on it.

However, how would I go about developing these games or even apps.  The new Nokias seem to be gaining market share now, so then surely there is a growing market (although not active) for app development.